# Unable to build MonoDevelop because of missing assemblies in the QAC

Tags: macos, mono, monodevelop

I wanted to restrain from asking for more help on building MonoDevelop on Mac OSX but at this point it seems like the only way I can progress.

I have followed this guide: http://monodevelop.com/Developers/Mac_Support/Building_MonoDevelop_on_OS_X

I am up to simply running the project with `make run`, however I receive the following error:

```
aquageneral$ make rundyld: warning, unknown environment variable: DYLD_LIBRARY_FALLBACK_PATH
cd main && make run
dyld: warning, unknown environment variable: DYLD_LIBRARY_FALLBACK_PATH
dyld: warning, unknown environment variable: DYLD_LIBRARY_FALLBACK_PATH
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin" PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/Users/aquageneral/Desktop/monodevelop/monodevelop/local-config:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig:" LD_LIBRARY_PATH="" DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="" MONO_GAC_PREFIX="/usr/local:" MONODEVELOP_LOCALE_PATH="/Users/aquageneral/Desktop/monodevelop/monodevelop/main/build/locale" MONO_ADDINS_REGISTRY="/Users/aquageneral/Desktop/monodevelop/monodevelop/main/build/bin" UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 exec -a "monodevelop" /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/bin/mono --debug /Users/aquageneral/Desktop/monodevelop/monodevelop/main/build/bin/MonoDevelop.exe --no-redirect
dyld: warning, unknown environment variable: DYLD_LIBRARY_FALLBACK_PATH
dyld: warning, unknown environment variable: DYLD_LIBRARY_FALLBACK_PATH
ERROR [2012-06-24 19:00:28Z]: Error setting process name
System.DllNotFoundException: libc.dylib
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoDevelop.Core.Runtime:prctl (int,byte[],intptr,intptr,intptr)
  at MonoDevelop.Core.Runtime.unixSetProcessName (System.String name) [0x00000] in /Users/aquageneral/Desktop/monodevelop/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Core/Runtime.cs:257 
  at MonoDevelop.Core.Runtime.SetProcessName (System.String name) [0x00010] in /Users/aquageneral/Desktop/monodevelop/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Core/Runtime.cs:240 
ERROR [2012-06-24 19:00:28Z]: Error initialising GLib logging.
System.DllNotFoundException: libglib-2.0.0.dylib
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) GLib.Marshaller:g_malloc (uintptr)
  at GLib.Marshaller.StringToPtrGStrdup (System.String str) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at GLib.Log.SetLogHandler (System.String logDomain, LogLevelFlags flags, GLib.LogFunc logFunc) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.GLibLogging.set_Enabled (Boolean value) [0x00030] in /Users/aquageneral/Desktop/monodevelop/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide/GLibLogging.cs:50 
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeStartup.Run (MonoDevelop.Ide.MonoDevelopOptions options) [0x00056] in /Users/aquageneral/Desktop/monodevelop/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide/IdeStartup.cs:88 
FATAL ERROR [2012-06-24 19:00:28Z]: MonoDevelop failed to start. Some of the assemblies required to run MonoDevelop (for example gtk-sharp, gnome-sharp or gtkhtml-sharp) may not be properly installed in the GAC.
System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for Gtk.Application ---> System.DllNotFoundException: glibsharpglue-2
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) GLib.Thread:glibsharp_g_thread_supported ()
  at GLib.Thread.get_Supported () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Gtk.Application..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeStartup.Run (MonoDevelop.Ide.MonoDevelopOptions options) [0x0007e] in /Users/aquageneral/Desktop/monodevelop/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide/IdeStartup.cs:95 
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeStartup.Main (System.String[] args) [0x0004f] in /Users/aquageneral/Desktop/monodevelop/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide/IdeStartup.cs:503 
make[1]: *** [runmd] Error 255
make: *** [run] Error 2
```

I have reinstalled the Mono MDK from scratch, and I have even ran:
`export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib:/lib:/usr/lib` from the same terminal as well a second time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning messages indicate that you've set `DYLD_LIBRARY_FALLBACK_PATH`, but it should be `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH`. Though if you re-exported it correctly, you should be able to ignore that warning.

What's actually causing a problem here for you though, is that MonoDevelop's configure script captures the value of `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` when you `./configure`, and uses it when you `make run`. This is supposed to be a convenience, but here it's captured an empty value.

Simply run `./configure` again to make it capture the new value, then `make` and `make run`.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick - the application finally launched! There are still a few errors but I am not sure if they matter: `Error while compiling generated serializer
/var/folders/zv/426pbwvs0pd0dpspf4kdxmp00000gn/T/14a8e82f/6ef7b232.cs(58,41) : error CS0584: Internal compiler error: Method not found: 'Stetic.LibraryCache.FindTypeDefinition'.
` Thanks for your help, I will try getting Unity compiled. Almost forgot, I also re-pulled from Git, it didn't work when I tried it prior.